# Resume Activity from notification

Tags: android

i am new in android and i need some help.

I'm doing a music player target api 10. I have a service which reproduce music in background and it's bind to an activity which display graphical reproduction, like play button, next song, among other things.

In the activity i override onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ), so when home, or menu buttons are clicked then a notification is created.

I created the notification like this:

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_notify)
                        .setContentTitle(songsList.get(currentSongIndex))
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");

             mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

             Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
             resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

             PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(
                 this,
                 0,
                 resultIntent,
                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
             );

             mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

             NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                     (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

             mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

the problems is that i want to do this when the back button is pressed too (not only with menu and home button), but it doesn't work...it force aplication to close because a nullPointerExeption in the activity bound to service.

I have to mention that the notification is created on back pressed, the problems is when i click the notification to return the activity...

Heare the all method:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event ) {
  if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU  || keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME || keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
  if (mServ.isPlaying()){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play_notify)
            .setContentTitle(songsList.get(currentSongIndex))
            .setContentText("Hello World!");
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =PendingIntent.getActivity(
              this,
              0,
              resultIntent,
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                 );
         mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        // Sets an ID for the notification
         int mNotificationId = 001;
        // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
                     (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Builds the notification and issues it.
                    mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            super.onBackPressed () ;

        }
        else
            moveTaskToBack(true);
         }
       return super.onKeyDown(keycode,event); 
     }
    return false;
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the stack trace that's generated when you tap the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `onBackPressed` method is used for handling back button press.

But I'd advise you to change the approach. As it's not guaranteed that your activity gets any messages (except for `onSaveInstanceState`) you better not rely on that. Try use `startForeground` method of the service in which you can define notification icon, it's very helpfull for long-running services.